# SQL Server: Selecting Value That was met in the Where Criteria

Tags: sql-server, select

My query selects records where given item types were ordered and I would like it to return a column that has the value for the criteria which a given record has met.

For example (since the above explanation is probably confusing):

```
DECLARE @Item1 VARCHAR(8) = 'Red Shoes',
        @Item2 VARCHAR(8) = 'Brown Belt',
        @Item3 VARCHAR(8) = 'Blue Shoes',
        @Item4 VARCHAR(8) = 'Black Belt'

SELECT DISTINCT ord.Order_number, 
                ord.Item_number, 
                ord.Item_type, 
                ord.Item_desc, 
                link.Item_number AS linked_item_number   

FROM Ordertbl ord
LEFT JOIN Item_tables link
    ON link.item_number = ord.item_number
WHERE link.Item_number IN (@Item1,@Item2,@Item3,@Item4) AND
      ord.Item_number NOT IN (@Item1,@Item2,@Item3,@Item4)
```

Desired Outcome: All items that were ordered whenever Item1,2,3, or 4 were ordered and, for each record, a field that depicts what item (1,2,3, or 4) was the *source* for that record being returned.

Using multiple Union queries with where criteria set to a single item provides the desired outcome if I set the linked_item_number field to the queried item, but that method is less than ideal because, at times, large numbers of items may be queried.

Comment: So you want to pass multiple items and subjs? Have you considered using a table variable/parameter?

Comment: So is `Item_number` a number or a string? The naming convention suggests a number, but your where clause is referencing what appears to be descriptions of items, so your query is kind of confusing.

Comment: Seems like you're missing a piece here. Do you have an Item lookup table and an Order table?

Comment: What are the `@SubjX` variables?

Comment: Item_number is a number and the variables named 'Subjx' should be have been named 'Itemx'. This error has been fixed in an edit.

Comment: `where Item_number in (@Item1,@Item2,@Item3,@Item4) and
      Item_number Not in (@Item1,@Item2,@Item3,@Item4)` This always contradict each other.  Your query will always return `NULL`

Comment: @Eric I managed to omit a table join from original post, which has been corrected, that may somewhat add to the issue that you commented on, but it still needs fixed. That where clause is attempting to remove records where an item is linked to itself;  so I do not get a record where brown shoes were ordered in the same order where brown shoes were ordered.

Comment: I think one issue that is reducing readability is that your tables aren't aliased, nor are you qualifying your column names with the source table. While this will work as long as none the columns names in the query appear in both tables, it makes it difficult for other people to understand the schema just by looking at the query.

Comment: What if an item is returned because the order it was in had two of the items from your list? Would you want two records (one for each order item and linked item pair), or would you only want one record with some sort of compound value to show that there were two triggering items in the order? What if the order only had 1 (or more) item(s) from the triggering list?

Comment: @digital.aaron The ideal outcome would be to have two records returned as to show that each of the items is linked to 'main item'.

Comment: @k1234 In that case, check out my edited answer. It should be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Edited: I've updated my answer a bit, and expanded on a few areas using my best guesses, but hopefully they help help illuminate the points I'm making.

Using `NOT IN` in a `WHERE` clause is really bad for performance. It would be better to convert your filters into tables, and then `JOIN` them to your order table.

But before we get to that, let's make a few DML assumptions here that will help keep things clear. Let's say you have two tables like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE Ordertbl
(
    Order_number INT
    ,Item_number INT
    --you might have more columns in your table
)

CREATE TABLE Item_tables
(
    Item_number INT
    ,Item_type INT
    ,Item_desc VARCHAR(8)
    --again, you might have more columns in your table
)
```

I'm also going to assume that the details about an item are in `Item_tables` and not in `Ordertbl`, because that makes the most sense for a database design to me.

My original answer had the following block of text next:

> In this scenario, you'd need two additional tables, one for the list
>   of Items in `where Item_number in (@Item1,@Item2,@Item3,@Item4)` which
>   would have the corresponding Item_numbers. The other table would be
>   the list of Subjs in `Item_number Not in
>   (@Subj1,@Subj2,@Subj3,@Subj4,@Subj5,@Subj6,@Subj7)`, again, including
>   the Item_number for those Subj records.

The question has been updated so that the `WHERE` clause is different than it was when I wrote the original version of my answer. The design pattern still applies here, even if the variables being used are different.

So let's create a temp table to hold all of our "triggering" items, and then populate it.

```
DECLARE @Item1 VARCHAR(8) = 'Red Shoes',
        @Item2 VARCHAR(8) = 'Brown Belt',
        @Item3 VARCHAR(8) = 'Blue Shoes',
        @Item4 VARCHAR(8) = 'Black Belt'

CREATE TABLE #TriggeringItems
(
    Item_desc VARCHAR(8)
)

INSERT INTO #TriggeringItems
(
    Item_desc
)
SELECT @Item1
    UNION
SELECT @Item2
    UNION
SELECT @Item3
    UNION
SELECT @Item4
```

If you had more filter variables to add, you could keep `UNIONing` them onto the `INSERT`.

So now we have our temp table and we can filter our query. Great!

...right?

Well, not quite. Our input parameters are descriptions, and our foreign key is an INT, which means we'll have to do a few extra joins to get our key values into the query. But the general idea is that you'd use an `INNER JOIN` to replace `WHERE ... IN ...`, and a `LEFT JOIN` to replace the `WHERE ... NOT IN ...` (adding a `WHERE X IS NULL` clause, where `X` is the key of the `LEFT JOIN`ed table)

If you didn't care about getting the triggering items back in your `SELECT`, then you could just go ahead with replacing the `WHERE ... IN ...` with an `INNER JOIN`, and that would be the end of it. But let's say you only wanted the list of items that WEREN'T the triggering items. For that, you would need to join `Ordertbl` to itself, to get the list of Order_numbers with triggering items within them. Then you could `INNER JOIN` one side to the temp table, and `LEFT JOIN` the other half. I know my explanation might be hard to follow, so let me show you what I mean in code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT onums.Order_number, 
                orditems.Item_number, 
                orditems.Item_type, 
                orditems.Item_desc, 
                tinums.Item_number AS linked_item_number   
FROM #TriggeringItems ti
INNER JOIN Item_tables tinums ON ti.Item_desc = tinums.Item_desc
INNER JOIN Ordertbl onums ON tinums.Item_number = onums.Item_number
INNER JOIN Ordertbl ord ON onums.Order_number = ord.Order_number
INNER JOIN Item_tables orditems ON ord.Item_number = orditems.Item_number
LEFT JOIN #TriggeringItems excl ON orditems.Item_desc = excl.Item_desc
WHERE excl.Item_desc IS NULL
```

`onums` is our list of order numbers, but `ord` is where we're going to pull our items from. But we only want to return items that aren't triggers, so we `LEFT JOIN` our temp table at the end and add the `WHERE excl.Item_desc IS NULL`.

Comment: @digitial.aaron Thank you for reply. I am currently attempting to apply it. Also, my original question has been edited to include the fact that Order_number is from Ordertbl, not from Item_tables

Comment: I am running into problems when attempting to create a temp table for the inner join (creating a temp table is somewhat beyond my limited technical SQL knowledge). Once the temp table #IteimSearchList is created, how can that table then be joined to Item_tables?

Comment: The temp table will act just like a regular table for the join syntax. You can see I joined `#ItemSearchList` to `Item_tables` with the following: `INNER JOIN #ItemSearchList isl ON i.Item_number = isl.Item_number`

Comment: First off, thank you for continued assistance, this query will be valuable for my current, and future, projects. I am attempting to apply your solution, but an error stating that "There is already an object named '#TriggeringItems' in the database" keeps returning. I am getting out of my lane a fair amount so my trouble shooting efforts were not effective. I attempted to drop the table if it exists before creating it, but that was not effective.

Comment: @k1234 Add this to the top of your script to drop the temp table if it exists: `IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TriggeringItems') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TriggeringItems`

Comment: @digital.arron The recommendation in the above comment cleared the error, thank you. Now, the query runs, but 0 records are returned. If I remove `WHERE excl.Item_desc IS NULL` the items in the temp table are returned.